# how to append a value in div which i select

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have to append a td in selected div table which is creating dynamically. right now when i clicking on button its appending in all divs. i want to append in only which div i select.
html-

```js
$(function() {
  $(".module").click(function() {
    $(".work-area").append("<div class='col-md-4 box'><table></table></div>")
  });

  $(".component").click(function() {
    $(".box table").append('<tr><td>x<td><tr>');
  });
});
```

```css
/* Following CSS is not a part of original question. */
.box{
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <button class="module">Module-1</button><br/><br/>
    <button class="module">Module-1</button><br/><br/>
    <button class="module">Module-1</button><br/><br/>
    <button class="module">Module-1</button><br/><br/>

    <hr>
    <button class="component">component-1</button><br/><br/>
    <button class="component">component-1</button><br/><br/>
    <button class="component">component-1</button><br/><br/>
    <button class="component">component-1</button><br/><br/>

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="work-area">


    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: So what is your question ? your code doesn't work and nothing append

Comment: How are you selecting the div? Does your div have a unique id? Or are you saying "append after the div I click on"? (these have different solutions)

Comment: *selected div table which is creating dynamically* Does this means last added element is there any specific case?

Comment: Your code does ... something. It's not entirely clear from your description what the intended result is.

Comment: @Damon try following use-case: Click `module-1` button more than 1 times and then click in `component-1` button. This adds `x` in all `div`s. I guess OP wants to add to the latest new div and not to all.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this, it might be what you are looking for but its a bit unclear.

Now you can select a `box` and when its selected component will add to the selected box

```
$(function() {
  $(".module").click(function() {
    $(".work-area").append("<div class='col-md-4 box'><table></table></div>")
  });

  var divselected = null;
  $(".work-area").on("click", ".box", function() {
    $(".box").removeClass("focus");
    divselected = $(this);
    $(this).addClass("focus");

  })

  $(".component").click(function() {
    if (divselected != null) {
      divselected.append('<tr><td>x<td><tr>');
    }

  });
});
```

**Working demo**

```js
$(function() {
  $(".module").click(function() {
    $(".work-area").append("<div class='col-md-4 box'><table></table></div>")
  });

  var divselected = null;
  $(".work-area").on("click", ".box", function() {
    $(".box").removeClass("focus");
    divselected = $(this);
    $(this).addClass("focus");
  })

  $(document).mouseup(function(e) {
    var container = $(".box, .component");

    if (!container.is(e.target) && container.has(e.target).length === 0) {
      $(".box").removeClass("focus");
      divselected = null
    }
  });

  $(".component").click(function() {
    if (divselected != null) {
      divselected.append('<tr><td>x<td><tr>');
    }

  });
});
```

```css
/* Following CSS is not a part of original question. */

.box {
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  margin: 5px;
}

.box.focus {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <button class="module">Module-1</button><br/><br/>
    <button class="module">Module-1</button><br/><br/>
    <button class="module">Module-1</button><br/><br/>
    <button class="module">Module-1</button><br/><br/>

    <hr>
    <button class="component">component-1</button><br/><br/>
    <button class="component">component-1</button><br/><br/>
    <button class="component">component-1</button><br/><br/>
    <button class="component">component-1</button><br/><br/>

  </div>
  <div class="col-md-8">
    <div class="work-area">


    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```